# "Iterate" vs. "Reiterate"

Tags: meaning, etymology

**Definition of [*iterate*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/iterate):**

> to say or do again or again and again

**Definition of [*reiterate*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reiterate):**

> to state or do over again or repeatedly sometimes with wearying effect

The distinction seems to be that *reiterate* is conventionally used when the repeating of this thing is supplementary to the attempt to convey the point at hand. I don't think I've ever heard *iterate* used similarly. Would it be wrong or awkward to? If not, then why are there two different words? When should one be used over the other?

Comment: The only time I've heard "iterate" used properly was during a self-defence course. Learning to defend yourself and hearing English used perfectly at the same time...you can't beat it!

Answer (score 4):

To me, to *iterate* is to do the same thing many times in mathematics or some other process. It may involve either gradually approaching a solution or going though a list.

Meanwhile to *reiterate* would be to say something one more time to remind a listener or reader of an important point.

No doubt they had similar meanings of repetition at some point in time, but I feel they now have different meanings and contexts for use.

Answer (score 2):

iterate has to do with repeating an action - reiterate has to do with repeating verbally

Comment: There seem to be several different opinions as to how best to distinguish two similar words that most competent speakers would normally use in different contexts without even *thinking* about exactly why. But your distinction seems better than anything else posted so far.

Answer (score 1):

I see a clear difference between *iterate* and *reiterate*:

To *iterate* is to perform the same actions, process, function, or procedure on a ***series*** of subjects or targets.  (The action is repetitive, but the subject is different for each iteration; you perform the actions once per subject.)

To *reiterate* is to perform the same process, function, or procedure on ***the same*** subject or target multiple times (you repeat the same actions on the same target, presumably because the desired result was not achieved on the first try).

In specific circumstances, *reiterate* and *repeat* can be synonymous, especially when the action is "talk to someone".

Answer (score 0):

The difference is subtle, but *iterate* focuses on one particular instance of a repeating action, while *reiterate* calls additional attention to the repetition itself.

Comment: There's a word used to mean a single instance of the repeating action: *iteration*.  (It can also mean the process of repetition, though)

Comment: @BenVoigt And *iterate* is the verb you use to express *iteration.*

Answer (score 0):

In math and computer science "iterate" has ad additional meaning which is to do again with a different value often in sequence. for example "Since we need to take a list of numbers and convert them from feet to meters we iterate over the list applying the formula to each member."

Comment: That's not really an additional meaning, it's the same as the primary one.

Answer (score 0):

Reiterate is when you are repeating yourself.  "Let me reiterate the following points:"
Iterate is when you are repeating the words of another.  " I can iterate it no better than what is written here (URL) by another of our members."

Answer (score 0):

Reiterate is not a replacement for repeat. It is used in places where we emphasize by repeating. 
Iterate is a replacement for repeat but more than once usually to achieve accuracy or convergence.

Comment: This is true but it doesn't really add anything to the existing answers.

Answer (score -1):

Reiterate: when you stressfully give the same statement again, repeat the same act or stressfully remind someone of a previous act

iterate: just doing same act repeatedly